# mysql Update query customize according if field is present

Tags: php, mysql

I presently have this data

```
$user=$postData['user_name'];
$phone_no=$postData['phone_no'];

$qry = "UPDATE users SET user_name = '$user', phone_no = '$phone_no' WHERE id = 1"
```

I want to update user_name only if value is present in $postData['user_name'] same is the case for phone_no , if data present in $phone_no then only phone_no should be updated .

Comment: And what have you tried to get it working like that?

Comment: if() or switch() is new for you? => php.net

Comment: @donald123 those command where added only last week please :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to construct your query in segments:

```
$user = $postData['user_name'];
$phone_no = $postData['phone_no'];

$update = array();
if($user) {
    $update[] = "user_name = '$user'";
}

if($phone_no) {
    $update[] = "phone_no = '$phone_no'";
}

if(count($update)) {
    $query = "UPDATE users SET ";
    $query .= implode(",", $update);
    $query .= " WHERE id = 1";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dynamic query by imploding available values.

Here is an example by using PDO with prepared statements:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database', 'username', 'password');

$user = $postData['user_name'];
$phone_no = $postData['phone_no'];  

$set = $values = array();
if(!empty($user)) {
    $set[] = 'user_name = :user_name';
    $values[':user_name'] = $user;
}

if(!empty($phone_no)) {
    $set[] = 'phone_no = :phone_no';
    $values[':phone_no'] = $phone_no;
}

if(!empty($set)) {
    $set = implode(', ', $set);

    $sql = 'UPDATE users SET ' . $set . ' WHERE id = 1';
    $update = $db->prepare($sql);
    $update->execute($values);
}
```

If those are just two, the above way is okay, but if it has 10 fields, you might need to loop it instead:

```
$set = $values = array();
$column_names = array('user_name', 'phone_no', 'id');
foreach($postData as $key => $value) {
    if(!empty($value) && in_array($key, $column_names)) {
        $set[] = "$key = :$key";
        $values[":$key"] = $value;
    }
}
```